# C++ - Creating objects by reading from a file, but the instream isn't stopping at the end of the file. `std::invalid_argument what() stoi`

Tags: c++

So, the following is just a tiny example of a problem I'm having with a much larger program.

By making it output ****, I was able to figure out that after it reaches what should be the end of the file, the while loop keeps going on. I can't get it to stop at the end of file.

Here is an example of what the .data file contains

```
/***
56
John

43
Lisa

91
Jim

***/
```

And here is the code

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Contact {
public:
  int ID;
  string name;
  void setID(int newID) {
    ID = newID;
  }
  void setName(string newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& lineIn, Contact& newContact) {
    string tempName;
    string tempID;
    string emptyLine;
    getline(lineIn, tempID);
    newContact.setID(stoi(tempID));
    getline(lineIn, tempName);
    newContact.setName(tempName);
    getline(lineIn, emptyLine);
    return lineIn;
  }
};

const string CONTACT_FILE = "contacts.data";
std::map<int,Contact> ContactsMap;

int main() {
  ifstream fin( CONTACT_FILE );
  if (fin) {
    Contact c;
    while ( fin >> c  ) {
      std::cout << "\n********";
      ContactsMap[c.ID] = c;
    }
    fin.close();
  }
  cout << "\nContactsMap.at(56).name";

}
```

Comment: Side note: Should friends get implemented in the class? I thought the point of them was that they get implemented outside the class, but have access to the private members.

Comment: Yes, I do that in the actual program I'm working on. I just thought it would be quicker and simpler to do it this way for the purpose of this question

Comment: Oh Got you. Thanks for doing that, btw.

Comment: Your code looks okay to me. Maybe someone with more experience can find the problem.

Comment: Have you tried, instead of just outputting a bunch of asterisks, outputting the actual values you're getting? Which I guess should be done in the operator before you try `stoi`.

Comment: OK, I just put `cout << "\nstring tempID is: " << tempID << "\nconverted to int: " << stoi(tempID);` right after `getline(lineIn, tempID);` It outputs everything correctly, for example `string tempID is: 43`. But right at the end it outputs `string tempID is:` with nothing afterwards, then the next line has the same error before it can output `converted to int`. So I know it's reading an empty value and trying to convert it. But the problem I'm having  is that it doesn't stop reading before it gets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your problem is in `operator>>` implementation. If `getline()` does not read the line, it does nothing, thus your loop will continue on with running. So what you can do is:

```
if(!getline(lineIn, tempID))
    return lineIn;
```

and do it every time you call `getline()`.

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& lineIn, Contact& newContact) {
    string tempName;
    string tempID;
    string emptyLine;
    if(!getline(lineIn, tempID)) return lineIn;
    newContact.setID(stoi(tempID));
    if(getline(lineIn, tempName)) return lineIn;
    newContact.setName(tempName);
    if(getline(lineIn, emptyLine)) return lineIn;
    return lineIn;
}
```

EDIT: @Johns way of dealing with this is better, but I hope from my answer you can see clearly what you need to do with your code to make it work.

Comment: Not sure why, but John's way didn't work for me. It kept on reading. But yours did work. I'm not sure why yours did but his didn't, because comparing your two answers seems to test the same thing in the if statement. Regardless, it worked. Thank-you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you aren't checking for errors in your overloaded `operator>>`. So the getlines are failing but you are still trying to set the values in your contact. Try this instead

```
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& lineIn, Contact& newContact) {
      string tempName, tempID, emptyLine;
      if (getline(lineIn, tempID) && getline(lineIn, tempName) && getline(lineIn, emptyLine)) {
          newContact.setID(stoi(tempID));
          newContact.setName(tempName);
      }
      return lineIn;
  }
```

I suppose the empty line at the end isn't vital. In which case you could move the last getline out of the if statement.

For extra security you should check that `tempID` is in the form of an integer, and set the failbit on the stream if it is not.

Comment: I'm going to implement that security check you mentioned. Can always improve my code